# Create External table In Impala - Error

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, impala

I'm using Hadoop EMR (AWS).

I tried to create an external table (based on specific location in S3) and got the error below:

> ERROR: AnalysisException: null CAUSED BY: RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found CAUSED BY:
>   ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found

When creating a non-external table (without the location) then it's working.

On hive there is no problem with both kind of tables.

Any idea what can I do to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Impala does not current support S3.

Answer (score 0):

Today Impala is working with HDFS only. Cloudera promise support for S3 in 2015 (look on their roadmap http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/whats-next-for-impala-focus-on-advanced-sql-functionality/) 
There is Impala flavor (called ImpalaToGo) which do work with S3. https://github.com/ImpalaToGo/ImpalaToGo/wiki
Disclaimer - I am deeply involved in this project.